# html - css check for chrome, ie & firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

css works for firefox but not ie or chrome. How to fix the css so that at least IE works like firefox.

**Firefox:**

[image]

**IE:**

[image]

The image is in the background as well but should be transparent.

**Chrome:**

[image]

**The HTML**:

```
<center><div id="slideshowContentArea" style="display:none; width:500px; height:300px">
    <div class='nav'><a id='prev' href='#'>Prev</a>&nbsp&nbsp<a id='next' href='#'>Next</a></div> 
    <div id="slideshow" class="pics" style="position: relative; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; height:250px; width:395px">&nbsp;</div>
</div></center>

        $('#slideshow').cycle(
            { fx: 'fade', timeout: 3000, speed: 500, 
              pager: '#slideshow', before: setBGBefore, prev:'#prev',next:'#next',after:onAfter
            }
            );
        function setBGBefore() {
        $(this).css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + $(this).find('img').attr('src') + ')', 
        'background-position': 'center top', 'background-color': 'transparent' });
        $(".welcomeBox div").html($(this).find('span').html());
        }
```

Comment: Well, to fix the CSS me must see the CSS. Can you post it?

Comment: @Blender: I am sorry, the css is embeded inside the setbgbefore function

Comment: That isn't the whole CSS, I'm quite sure.

Comment: @Blender: well, Sharepoint uses it's own core.css perhaps that is overwriting the custom css.

Comment: Found a solution. Just had to ask a co-worker. I added background-repeat:no-repeat; and now it's all good in IE and Firefox.

Comment: @Amber. If that was your only issue, you should have made it clear in your question...

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can tell you the browser in use:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

**Update.**
The question title was "**check for chrome, ie & firefox**" that's what I've answered. It's up to the OP if he wishes to implement a more elegant solution.

Comment: The right answer is not to sniff the browser, but to find a proper solution that produces the same output in all browsers.

Comment: The way margins and padding work across browsers differs - especially with older versions - a quick browser sniff to correct very minor issues isn't a bad approach.

Comment: Using a CSS reset may help address some of the padding and margin issues that Mikaveli mentioned.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Comment: in IE: this is the only error developer tool gave. SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited.